# JavaScript combines multiple arrays based on data

Tags: javascript

**When type equals all, I need to combine two arrays into one. I have the code, but it gets the wrong result。**

```js
const arr = [{value: 'aa'}, {value: 'bb'}];
const arr2 = [{type: 'all'}, {type: 'text', value: 'a2'}, {type: 'all'}]
arr.forEach((item, index) => {
  arr2.forEach((items, indexs) => {
    if (items.type === 'all') {
      items.value = arr[index].value
    }
  })
})
console.log(arr2)
```

**I hope to get this result**

```js
arr2 = [{type: 'all', value: 'aa'}, {type: 'text', value: 'a2'}, {type: 'all', value: 'bb'}]
console.log(arr2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a good idea to mutate the data that you're looping over.

If I understand correctly, you need to iterate through `arr2` and intersperse items from `arr` when type is `all`.

I'd use `Array.map` for this sort of thing:

```js
const arr = [{value: 'aa'}, {value: 'bb'}];
const arr2 = [{type: 'all'}, {type: 'text', value: 'a2'}, {type: 'all'}]

const combined = arr2.map(({type, ...rest})=>type==='all'?{type, ...arr.shift()}:{type, ...rest})

console.log(combined)
```